# Annoying XCode Source Kit bug with multiple targets

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, macos

I'm struggling with this problem for nearly half a year now with multiple XCode versions and Macs.

I can't reproduce bug steps exactly but the things go off when project has multiple targets like for Mac and iOS.

First of all XCode declines to take #if os into account and always highlight syntax only in one type of sections. E.g. if I have os(iOS) and os(OSX) somewhere it will chose only one and highlight only them.

Same goes for autocompletion. Things just not working in that type of projects.

I really dont know what to do since developmenet process turns into struggling. I dont want to split my project into multiple one, I'm happy with multi-target setup.

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please try to explain better and add some pictures

Comment: Report the issue to Apple.  Only they can fix it.

Comment: Well I just wonder maybe I confused some settings and that's why XCode cant define what code to highlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost a year late.
Anyway I faced the same situation where a multi target OSX/iOS application in Xcode did not take into account the #if TARGET_OS_IPHONE conditional and failed to autocomplete method names from framework only showing the iOS variant.
Found a solution, based on [this blog entry](https://medium.com/@_achou/one-weird-trick-to-fix-autocomplete-in-xcode-9f19dc856944%20this%20blog%20entry) : you have to clearly state the Framework search path on each target in Build settings

[image: multi target Framework search path]

Edit: This line was present in the iOS target settings. I copy/pasted it to the MacOS target in Xcode where it was automatically adjusted to the right path.

Edit 2: Loosely related but if you run in trouble with interface builder picking wrong classe files see [this answer I just posted in another old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44865270/1764008).